# "Command not found" when try send a file to IPFS

Tags: go, ipfs

I'm want to use IPFS in my project, then, I'm studying about Go IPFS API.
Then, I wrote this very simple code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    sh "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api"
)

func main() {
    shell := sh.NewShell("https://ipfs.io")

    bufferExample := bytes.NewBufferString("Hello IPFS Shell tests")
    mhash, err := shell.AddNoPin(bufferExample)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // ends where
    }

    fmt.Println(mhash)
}
```

But I receive the error `panic: add: command not found`, and I don't understand why. I already have IPFS in my computer (I can run the deamon, for example). I also installed the Go IPFS library with development dependencies.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User Magik6k answered my question in [another forum](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/error-command-not-found-when-im-using-go-ipfs-api/916):

> You can't use the public IPFS gateway to add content. For this you
>   need locally running daemon and pass it's API endpoint to NewShell
>   (localhost:5001 by default).
>
> Public gateways(ipfs.io, localhost:8080) only support a limited API
>   subset, see
>   https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/core/commands/root.go#L1412
>   for what is available

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with the various paths. The program is running and it's panicking because you have asked it to in case of an error:

```
mhash, err := shell.AddNoPin(bufferExample)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // ends where
}
```

The error `add: command not found` is a result of your system not being able to locate the [`add`](https://ipfs.io/docs/commands/#ipfs-add) command (error is an [http 404](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api/blob/master/request.go#L105)).

Have you installed IPFS command on your system? If not, try after doing that.

Comment: Yes, I already have installed the IPFS command. I can run the daemon, for example.